# Get time between two dates in months only in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datediff

I wrote this script to tell the time in-between two dates

```
$term_start   = date_create("2018-01-01");
$now          = date_create(date("2019-02-01"));
$diff         = date_diff($term_start,$now);
$amount_spent = $diff->format("%y %m");
echo $amount_spent;
```

But I want it only in months how do I force it to output 25 instead of 1 1?

Comment: `But I want it only in months how do I force it to output 25 instead of 1 1?` Sample input and output please?

Comment: write a value of `$row` in question.

Comment: @user5173426 done

Comment: `$diff->format("%y")*12 +  $diff->format("%m")`

Comment: why its 25 any reason or logic behind it?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama sorry the original example was 2 years and 1 month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is to get the months difference between two dates then you may try the following:

```
<?php
$term_start   = date_create("2017-01-01");
$now          = date_create(date("2019-02-01"));
$diff         = date_diff($term_start,$now);
$amount_spent = $diff->format("%y")*12 + $diff->format("%m");
echo $amount_spent;
?>
```

Output:

> 25

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$term_start = "2017-01-01";
$now        = "2019-02-01";
$ts1        = strtotime($term_start);
$ts2        = strtotime($now);
$year1      = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2      = date('Y', $ts2);
$month1     = date('m', $ts1);
$month2     = date('m', $ts2);
$diff       = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
echo $diff;
```

> Output: 25

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to calculate the number of seconds the difference is and divide with the number of seconds on a month (in average, 30 days).

```
$term_start   = "2017-01-01";
$now          = "2019-02-01";
echo floor((strtotime($now) - strtotime($term_start))/2592000);
// 25
```

This means you don't need to use DateTime which is a quite heavy.